# Replace printed statements in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

How to replace printed statements in Python 2.7, for example:

```
for i in range(100):
    print i,"% Completed"

#Result Must Be:
>>> 1 % Completed
```

The 1 must be **replaced** by 2 and so on. But not in different line or append on same line.

I tried searching about it, found solution such as

```
from __future__ import print_function
print("i: "+str(i),end="\r")
```

But they result in appended print statements. Is there any correction in my `print_function` or is there a different solution?

Comment: Not sure what result you want. do you want every statement printed in loop in single line?

Comment: I want the printed statement to be replaced by new statement, not in new lines or appended

Comment: For example, `1 % Completed` must become `2 % Completed` but not `1 % Completed 2 % Completed`

Comment: Can't you just replace `i` with `(i+1)` in the print statement?

Comment: @TomKarzes I don't want multiple printed lines or statement, i want the output replaced.

Comment: Your code works **if you run the script in a shell**, as does the code in the answers below. It **will not work** in an IDE (well, probably, I can't speak for them all), and clearly doesn't in yours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you want something like this:

```
>>> import sys, time
>>> for i in range(100):
...     time.sleep(0.1)
...     sys.stdout.write('%d %% Completed \r' % (i,))
...     sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: Sorry but I want the output replaced, not appended.

Comment: @CraziestHacker Did you run this?

Comment: Yes, just as you posted it

Comment: @CraziestHacker I don't see it appending to previous output on my shell. Did you miss that `\r` at the end of the string?

Comment: @CraziestHacker: Methinks you are running the code in an IDE, rather than a shell terminal?

Comment: I copied you statements, so no error in copying. My out put is as follows: `0 % Completed 
1 % Completed 
2 % Completed 
3 % Completed 
4 % Completed 
5 % Completed 
6 % Completed 
7 % Completed 
8 % Completed 
9 % Completed 
10 % Completed 
11 % Completed 
12 % Completed 
13 % Completed 
14 % Completed 
15 % Completed 
16 % Completed 
17 % Completed 
18 % Completed 
19 % Completed 
20 % Completed 
21 % Completed 
22 % Completed `

Comment: Yep, i only work on IDE, not on shell.

Comment: Copied where? To terminal directly? Not sure how you running it. May be try typing it out by hand and see?

Comment: Well, it ain't gonna work then. Will your code run in a shell when it's deployed? No, it'll be run in a shell.

Comment: Okay, it works on shell, but not on IDE. Thanks for your solutions though.

Comment: how to change it to Completed: 100% instead of 100% Compleated

Comment: FYI this didn't work (for me at least) using 'python' in the terminal (on ubuntu) but worked using 'ipython', 'python3 script.py' and in a jupyter notebook

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
from __future__ import print_function

for i in range(100):
    print('{0}% Completed\r'.format(i), end='')
print('100% Completed')
```

Set a higher range if you actually want to see it work for a few seconds.

Comment: Sorry but  I want the output replaced, not appended.

Comment: @CraziestHacker my code does replace the output, what are you talking about?

Comment: So, your answer is irrelevant, because my question clearly states replace output statement, but not append it.

Comment: @CraziestHacker the output is replaced, not appended. You are doing something wrong.