# Replace print statement output in Python 3.7

Tags: python-3.x, output

I need to make a timer, that replaces the output. For example:

`5`

This then replaces with `4` after one second and so on.

This no longer works:

- [Replace printed statements in Python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34338749/replace-printed-statements-in-python-2-7)

I have made a timer already as follows, but it doesn't do what I expected:

```py
from time import sleep
for i in range(4, -1, -1):
    print(i, end=" ")
    sleep(1)
```

The actual results are:

`4 3 2 1 0`

I'm using maCOS.

Comment: @Lamanus Doesn't work, I'm also using macOS not Windows

Comment: Use `print("\033c", end="")`to clear terminal and then execute your timer function.

Comment: There are 27 answers for windows, mac, and linux.

Comment: you cannot clear the terminal in your IDE, you need to run in terminal to see the effects*

Comment: Try `end='\r'` (carriage return).  It should return to the beginning of the line wihout a linefeed, but this is terminal-dependent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using the `DEL` ASCII character?

```
import time


for i in range(4, -1,-1):
    s = str(i)
    print(i, end='', flush=True)
    time.sleep(1)
    print('\u0008' * len(s), end='', flush=True)
print()
```

Answer (score 0):

For Mac or Linux you can use `print('\033c', end='')` to clear the terminal.
So your code should look like:

```
from time import sleep:

for i in range(4, -1,-1):
    print(i)
    print('\033c', end='')
    sleep(1)
```